# Сервер выдает ошибку 500

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$sdd_db_host;dbname=$sdd_db_name;charset=$charset";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $sdd_db_user, $sdd_db_pass, $opt);

$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Tokens (token ) VALUES(?)")->execute([$_GET["token"]]);
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: В логе ошибок сервера вестимо ;)

Comment: @Visman эх.....

Comment: Эх где мои экстрасенсорные способности. Вижу, вижу не установленно pdo и драйвер mysql... установи срочно...

Comment: @Naumov, вы шарлатан)) Все установлено)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка 500 означает, что сервер записал ошибку в лог, но не будет ее показывать на экране. То есть, надо смотреть в лог веб-сервера.

Если это локальный сервер, без доступа извне, то удобнее настроить его так чтобы ошибки выводились сразу на экран. Для этого можно добавить к коду строчку

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Comment: Вот что показывает log

syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: Это значит что очень устаревшая версия РНР. чтобы исправить ошибку надо заменить [....] на array(....). то есть написать execute(array($_GET["token"]))

Comment: @Naumov, что??? Тогда одна квадратная скобка не закроется)

Comment: обе скобки надо заменить. я выше дописал